# Need to transpose an excel table to create records

Tags: excel, transpose

I have a file with
1- a column for country
2- columns for each day of the year and under each column is the number of downloads made

I'm struggling to transpose the file in a way that creates records with the following columns :
1- Country
2- Date
3- Downloads

[google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CXcWmHQ2MVgxv9D-3Eq8Mwv920eV2QkcIjLt5B3VG4s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Excel or Google sheets? In Excel, you can use Power Query for that.

Comment: Took me about 2 minutes to download the file to Excel and use, as suggested by teylyn, PowerQuery to get the required result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply teylyn & norie. I've open Power Query and tried messing around in but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

deandaman

Here's the steps I took after downloading the sheet to Excel.

1 Goto Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

2 Selected the Territory column and then on the Transform tab selected Unpivot columns>Unpivot Other Columns.

3 Renamed the Attribute and Value columns to Date and Downloads respectively by double clicking their headers.

4 Selected File>Close & Load to return the data to Excel.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick and learned something new today!